# Drying solid oak flooring after water damage

Tags: hardwood-floor, water-damage

The builder didn't tighten the fresh water connection on the dishwasher in my newly purchased house. It dripped for days while I was out of town, and now an area of 2 feet by 15 feet has the TIG solid oak cupping. It's installed over plywood (crawl space).

Is there a way to manage the situation to minimize unevenness of the flooring?  I realize that this will require resanding and refinishing, but wondered if there is anything to minimize the amount of sanding.

Comment: This may require replacement of part of the floor. The builder should be held responsible for making this repair.

Comment: It is possible that it may dry out, I would put a fan on it , but agree with Jim. The builder or plumber should be responsible to repair this.

Comment: What is under the oak?  If it's chip board/sawdust board you will likely have to rip out the floor and sub floor.  The chip board swells when wet, and doesn't shrink back when it dries. You may also have mould issues under the oak.

Comment: There is 5/8 exterior plywood under the oak.  The plywood is on floor joists above a crawl space.